# Does database queries from cloud code count?

Tags: parse-platform

Parse has a 30 req/s limit. However it is not very clear what operations this is counting, for example I learned that cached queries do not count to this limit.

My question is if I call queries from the cloud code does the device-cloud operation count for the limit or does cloud-database operation count for the limit or do they both count?

Answer (score 2):

Think about Parse as a business. They make money based on the number of API requests submitted per second. Obviously the more you do, they more they potentially earn. So in your best interests, it's *always* safe to assume everything you query will be counted against you. Cached data is cached from a *past* query, so there is no reason to charge you again for the information that's already on the device. Or there may be, but I'll give Parse the benefit of the doubt on that one.

To answer your question specifically, yes, cloud code queries are no different, you will be charged 1 request per query.

See their official docs for a thorough breakdown on their allowances [HERE](https://www.parse.com/plans/faq) see the section titled 'What is Considered An API Request'. It literally leaves no room for assumption or misinterpretation :

> Anytime you make a network call to Parse on behalf of your app via the iOS, Android, JavaScript, Windows, Xamarin, Unity, or REST API, it counts as an API request.

Also, it might be a good thing to note it's 1 API request per *query* plus 1 additional request for each save operation (provided your saving anything)

***EDIT*** I forgot to mention local data store they recently introduced, again, it falls under the same stipulations when you pin the queries.